# Getting 2 letter language code with javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

If `navigator.language` returns `en-US`, but I only want `en` because I don't care about the `locale`, is there a preferred way to do this? Does angular have anything built in for this or should I just split on the `-`?

Answer (score 7):

use js `String.prototype.slice()` method.

```
navigator.language.slice(0,2);
```

Answer (score 4):

This will do:

```
navigator.language.substring(0,2);
```

Comment: You might want to use `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` methods after `substring(0,2)` for browser compatibility. As `(EN == en)` will return false.